# PuLP: Check whether the solution satisfies the constraints

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

So I ran CBC through pulp for 5 seconds and it gave out a solution but I am not sure it satisfies all the constraints. The value for each variable
is stored in `prob.variables()`. Is there a way I could run a similar code as the one below to check if the solutions satisfy the constraints given in `prob.constraints` - i.e. the solution is feasible ?

```
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(maxSeconds=5))

print 'Optimization status: %s' % LpStatus[prob.status]

for v in prob.variables():
    test whether 'v' satisfies prob.constraints
```

The setup of the problem and the constraints are very similar to the one given here: [github_code](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/examples/BeerDistributionProblem.py)

Cheers.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that includes some data?

Comment: Hi, I set up the problem almost the same way as here: https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/examples/BeerDistributionProblem.py
I could write the constraints explicitly above if it makes it clearer :). Thanks!

Comment: You can use `prob.solve(COIN(msg=1))` to print the CBC's output. For instance, I have "Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost", which implies the solution is feasible. Also, you may solve the problem using GLPK: `prob.solve(GLPK(msg=1))`.

Comment: Could you let us know *why* you need to check that the solution is feasible? We might avoid getting into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)..

Comment: This answer to a more recent, but very similar question might help anyone who lands here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69057455/4988601