# finding which constraints are not true when pulp optimization does not solve in time limit

Tags: optimization, constraints, pulp

I have a really big optimization that is not solving for large datasets.  I would like to look at the constraints to see which ones are holding and which ones are not.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a method of the `LpConstraint` class which allows you to easily check if it has been satisfied by the incumbent "solution" (not really a solution as does not satisfy all constraints). [link to LpConstraint docs](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/pulp.html#pulp.LpConstraint)

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34572919/4988601) was asked a while back, it has no answer, so I suspect this functionality doesn't exist. It might be worth submitting a feature request on the [pulp GitHub page](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp).

In the meantime you can probably hack together something that might work, along the lines of the following (where `prob` is your Pulp problem object):

```
soln_dict = {i.name: i.varValue for i in prob.variables()}

for c in prob.constraints.values():
    c_dict = c.toDict()
    # print(c_dict)
    satisfied = False
    
    LHS = sum([soln_dict[i['name']]*i['value'] for i in c_dict['coefficients']])
    LHS = LHS + c_dict['constant']
    
    if c_dict['sense'] == 0:
        satisfied = (LHS == 0)
   
    if c_dict['sense'] == -1:
        satisfied = (LHS <= 0)
    
    if c_dict['sense'] == 1:
        satisfied = (LHS >= 0)
   
    print(c)
    
    if satisfied:
        #print('LHS: ', LHS)
        print('is satisfied')
    else:
        #print('LHS: ', LHS)
        print('not satisfied')
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at the code looks like constraints have a valid function that is not in the docs

```
def valid(self, eps=0):
        val = self.value()
        if self.sense == const.LpConstraintEQ:
            return abs(val) <= eps
        else:
            return val * self.sense >= -eps
```

Comment: Nice find! One other thing to be aware of is that if you have lots of integer variables a likely thing to be not satisfied when you run out of time is the requirement that integer variables take integer values (and also upper/lower bounds on variables).