# In pulp, problem status is 2(optimal) but seems to ignore some constraints

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi, pulp

I'm trying to use Gurobi solver in pulp to solve a big linear programming problem. The status Gurobi returned is 2, which means that an optimal solution is available, but the solution doesn't meet my expectations. Here is the part where problem occurs:

```
MyProblem = pulp.LpProblem("MyProblem",LpMinimize)    # define the problem

# define variable
var_shengmu = {i: LpVariable(name=f"var_shengmu{i}", lowBound=0, upBound=100,cat=LpInteger) for i in range(N)}    
var_qiuyi_shengmu={i:{j:LpVariable(name=f"var_qiuyi_shengmu{i}{j}",cat=LpBinary)for j in range(i+1,N)} for i in range(N)}    

# add constraint
inf=10**6
eps=10**(-5)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        if some_condition:   # if var_shengmu[i] and var_shengmu[j] should be different
            #constraint (a)
            MyProblem+=(var_shengmu[i]-var_shengmu[j])<=-eps+inf*var_qiuyi_shengmu[i][j]    
            #constraint (b)                
            MyProblem+=(var_shengmu[j]-var_shengmu[i])>=eps-inf*(1-var_qiuyi_shengmu[i][j])
```

The last two lines above is an inequality constraint, I want to make var_shengmu[i] and var_shengmu[j] different. The idea is that if `var_shengmu[j]==var_shengmu[i]`, whatever `var_qiuyi_shengmu[i][j]` is, constraint(a) and (b) cannot be satisfied together.

However, the variables `var_shengmu` are all 0(from `var_shengmu[0]` to `var_shengmu[N-1]`) in the solution.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69019758/finding-which-constraints-are-not-true-when-pulp-optimization-does-not-solve-in) to print the constraints, and I surprisingly found that for all `i` and `j`, the constraint (b) I listed above are not satisfied. Some of my outputs are here:

```
-1000000*var_qiuyi_shengmu25472548 - var_shengmu17040 + var_shengmu17046 <= -1e-05
is satisfied
-1000000*var_qiuyi_shengmu25472548 - var_shengmu17040 + var_shengmu17046 >= -999999.99999
not satisfied
```

I'm extremely bewildered why the status is optimal but some constraints are ignored. Did I make something wrong? Thank in advance for your help!

By the way, you may wonder why don't I have an objective function. It's because the code I put here is only a small part of my problem, and in other parts, the objective function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved here.[https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues/592](https://here)
Pulp use solve matrix equations with floating point arithmetic with certain tolerances. I just increased eps, and it worked.